# loadUserByUsername argument empty with login post

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, authentication, spring-security

I'm trying to build a Login Form using Spring and I'm having problems reading the input parameters from It. When loadUserByUsername in the class UserDetailsService is called it recieves an empty Username value:

```
 @Override
@Transactional
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userService.ReadByUsername(userName);
    if(user == null){
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Utente non trovato");
    }
   UserBuilder builder = null;
    builder=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.withUsername(user.getUserName());
    String role = ("ROLE_"+user.getRole().toUpperCase());
    builder.authorities(role);

    builder.password(user.getPassword());
    return builder.build();

}
```

this is my configuration

```
 @Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(SUPERUSER_VEHICLE_MATCHER).access("hasRole('SUPERUSER')")
            .antMatchers(SUPERUSER_USER_MATCHER).access("hasRole('SUPERUSER')")
            .antMatchers("/vehicles/**").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/user/**").permitAll()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login/form")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login/form?error")
            .usernameParameter("userName")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/login/form?forbidden")
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/login/form?logout");

}
```

I'm using this Jsp Login Form

```
<div id="mainWrapper">
<div class="login-container">
    <div class="login-card">
        <div class="login-form">
            <c:url var="loginUrl" value="/login" />
            <form action="${loginUrl}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
              <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </c:if>

                <c:if test="${param.forbidden != null}">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <p>Accesso proibito</p>
                    </div>
                </c:if>

                <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">
                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                        <p>Logout effettuato</p>
                    </div>
                </c:if>

                <div class="input-group input-sm">
                    <label class="input-group-addon" for="userName"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userName" name="userName" placeholder="Nome Utente" required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group input-sm">
                    <label class="input-group-addon" for="password"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group input-sm">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="rememberme" name="rememberme">Ricordami
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                       value="${_csrf.token}" />

                <div class="form-actions">
                    <input type="submit"
                           class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-default" value="Log in">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think i'm having problems with the post request's parameters but i cannot find where and I couldn't "hardcode" them.
**Edit 1**

These are my console network logs [image]

[image]

Here is the intelliJ debugger and you can see that userName parameter is null [image]

Comment: And you're sure your `ReadByUsername` method is correct?

Comment: The argument (String username) is null

Comment: Did you check browser console (network) if there's any request being sent?

Comment: Yes, as you can see from the edit that is the request

Comment: The parameter is empty not null. You've added a custom filter to the chain, make sure that that doesn't destroy your request and make sure that your login screen is the one that is being used (it looks like the default one from Spring Security and not yours).

Comment: Thank you, maybe i mismatched the word username used from UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

Comment: I can't find any filter that destroys this field, i might rebuild it again from scratch